# Package a new base box

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying what should be a very simple procedure and bump into trouble.
I wish to build a base box with some pre-installed components. The overall procedure which I'm following is as follows:

1. Start a VM using ubuntu/trusty64 as my base
2. Install some new packages (postgres, apache and some apps)
3. vagrant package
   [now to test:]
4. vagrant box add --name new_box package.box
5. [in new dir] vagrant init new_box
6. vagrant up

At this point the problem appears where the startup lingers with these messages:

```
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

I'm using vagrant 1.7.2, VirtualBox 4.3.2. Host is windows 7.
I saw some information regarding persistent network connections however I didn't find those in /etc/udev

**Edit**:
Adding the boot.log section where the machine is stuck for a few minutes:

```
Cloud-init v. 0.7.5 running 'init-local' at Thu, 12 Mar 2015 14:42:15 +0000. Up 4.91 seconds.
cloud-init-nonet[5.46]: waiting 10 seconds for network device
cloud-init-nonet[15.47]: waiting 120 seconds for network device
cloud-init-nonet[135.47]: gave up waiting for a network device.
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is discussed [**here.**](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/3860)

According to the disucssion, *Vagrant has fixed* the bug. However `cloud-init` of [Ubuntu hasn't been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1315501) yet (at the time of posting).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

1. login with :gui by login/pass: vagrant/vagrant
2. modify the `/etc/rc.local` file 
   to include the line `sh /etc/init.d/networking restart` just before `exit 0`
3. disable :gui
4. vagrant up or vagrant reload

https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/391#issuecomment-2078383